# Apparent .bash_profile and .profile conflict in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I have an issue where, when I load up new terminal windows, I have to source the `~/.profile` to get my PHP path working correctly.

In essence of my issue is getting terminal to use MAMP PHP and MySQL instead of default.

I have the paths mapped out, but everytime I open a new window, I have to use the command

```
source ~/.profile
```

Is there a reason Mac OS X wouldn’t be registering/sourcing/[insert correct term here] the `.profile`?  I’ve read `.bash_profile` will override `.profile`, but the PHP path is defined in `.bash_profile` as well.

Here are the contents of each file.

The contents of `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/[username]/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/mysql"
```

The contents of `.profile`:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

Comment: The OS X Terminal opens a login shell by default, so it should source `.bash_profile`. Are you sure `.bash_profile` is sourced? Put an `echo "sourcing bash profile"` statement in it and try. And indeed, when `.bash_profile` exists, `.profile` will not be sourced (see [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html))

Comment: @slhck - is the way the path includes in my bash_profile not correct?  They way I'm reading it, I can give multiple path options in the `extport PATH=` line, or set t0 variables/params/whatever with export FOO=BAR and then include paths in succession via `:` separated values in the PATH declaration.  If bash is overriding profile, then is the PATH declaration in my bash busted?

Comment: @slhck - so, that might have been it.  I changed the order of the declaration in the bash_profile to `export PATH=/foo/bar:/Applications/whatever:$PATH` and it seems to be working.  So `$PATH` has to go at the end.  I didn't think that mattered, but if I had a nickel for every time I was wrong...

Comment: No, your PATH can go at the beginning as well, it just changes the order of preference. Perhaps there was another issue, but either way you may want to post an answer explaining how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is clear when you look at the logical order of what you have set in `.bash_profile` (which doesn’t work) when compared to `.profile` (which does work).

Here is your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/[username]/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/mysql"
```

And here is your `.profile`:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

The key to solving this is to look at where you are setting your new MAMP related items when compared to the default `$PATH`; order counts because the shell will act on (key thing) *the first item it finds in its list of user search paths*.

Knowing that you can breakdown the behavior you are seeing like this:

- In the `.profile` version you are setting `$MAMP_PHP` as a variable and then *prepending* it to the *beginning* of the `$PATH`.
- But in `.bash_profile` version you are *appending* this stuff *after* `$PATH`:  `:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/mysql`

So I would rework `.bash_profile` like this to make it work:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH:/Users/[username]/bin"
```

Note how I am using the `$MAMP_PHP` convention from `.profile`—which is a nice way of logically separating paths for human eyes—and how I simply set that value to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin` since I have no idea when this MySQL path would be used: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/mysql`.

From my vantage point using MAMP version 2.1.3 I don’t see an actual `mysql` binary in the path you have set. Traditionally this would be in the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/` directory along with other MAMP core binaries. So maybe your `.bash_profile` should be adjusted like this:

```
export MAMP_BIN=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_BIN:$MAMP_PHP:$PATH:/Users/[username]/bin"
```

Also, that `/Users/[username]/bin` seems kludgy and too specific for me. If you are maintaining a user directory specific `~/bin` directory you might want to just set it to `~/bin` like this:

```
export MAMP_BIN=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_BIN:$MAMP_PHP:$PATH":~/bin
```

Note how there are no double quotes (`"`) around the last `:~/bin` part; that allows `~/` to properly expand to your user’s home directory. That way you could cleanly use a `.bash_profile` setup like this on any user account where the user has `~/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Bash looks in your home directory for `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, and `.profile` in that order. Then bash will run the first of these that it finds and stop looking.

So, a solution for you, can be to source your `.profile` at the end of your `.bash_profile`, or simpler, copy both lines on your `.profile` at the end of your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: The OP said they had the respective lines in `.bash_profile` anyway. So it's apparently not sourced.

Answer (score 0):

In [Unix FAQ (for OS X)](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup) we can read:

> **Bash Startup Files**
>
> When a "login shell" starts up, it reads the file
>   "/etc/profile" and then "~/.bash_profile" or "~/.bash_login" or
>   "~/.profile" (**whichever one exists - it only reads ONE of these**,
>   checking for them in the order mentioned).
>
> When a "non-login shell" starts up, it reads the file "/etc/bashrc" and then the file "~/.bashrc".
>
> Note that when bash is invoked with the name "sh", it tries to mimic the startup sequence of the Bourne shell ("sh"). In particular, **a non-login shell invoked as "sh" does not read any dot files by default**. See the bash man page for details.

So if you've already `~/.bash_profile`, the file `~/.profile` won't be automatically read by bash, so you can add the following lines in your `~/.bash_profile` to load it:

```
# Load user profile file
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi
```